# ¿Cómo debería instanciar un evento en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Tengo una curiosidad con respecto a buenas practicas en JavaScript.
Examinando la pagina de w3schools y me encontré con estas tres formas:

**HTML**:

```
<element onclick="myScript">
```

**JavaScript**

```
object.onclick = function(){ myScript };
```

**addEventListener**

```
object.addEventListener( "click", myScript);
```

siendo esta última, no compatible con IE 8 ni versiones anteriores.

¿Qué forma de trabajar es más conveniente?¿O cada una tiene sus propias ventajas para ciertos aspectos?

Comment: De paso: w3schools no es considerada una fuente de información muy confiable, ni un buen lugar para aprender https://www.impressivewebs.com/w3schools-ugly-bad-good/ https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-hate-W3schools-com http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como comentas, los tres métodos van a funcionar, pero se diferencian en cómo operan y en el soporte que tiene. Qué forma deberías usar o es más conveniente va a depender de tu caso particular, las necesidades del proyecto, el soporte requerido...

Voy a poner un análisis/descripción/crítica de cada uno de ellos y al final mi recomendación (y ya de paso voy a añadir un método adicional que no se menciona en la pregunta pero que puede ser interesante).

---

### Scripts inline: `<element onclick="myScript">`

Esta sería la **manera más directa** de agregar el controlador de un evento para un elemento: directamente en el elemento en sí. Pero no te recomendaría que la usases:

- Es más difícil de mantener,
- Sólo puede haber un atributo onclick (pero puedes realizar varias operaciones desde uno solo),
- Entremezcla diferentes lenguajes (HTML y JavaScript),
- No permite utilizar algunos elementos de JavaScript (p.e. clausuras o funciones anónimas),
- En algunos casos directamente no funcionará (p.e. en las extensiones de [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)).

Como decía al principio de la lista, mi recomendación sería que no usases este método.

---

### Asignando el evento: `object.onclick = function(){ myScript };`

Esta manera es "similar" a la anterior, en el sentido de que estás asignando un valor al atributo `onclick` del elemento, pero como se ejecuta en el lado del código JavaScript, te va a dar algo más flexibilidad y libertad: puedes usar clausuras y funciones anónimas, y tienes más control sobre el entorno y el ámbito de las variables.

Pero este método tiene un problema que no debe obviarse: **sólo puede haber un atributo `onclick`**. ¿Qué quiere decir esto? Que si por cualquier motivo a lo largo de tu código vuelves a asignar el `onclick` a un elemento, el valor que tuviera antes se pierde.

Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código al botón le asignamos dos `onclick` pero sólo el último se ejecuta:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.onclick = function() { alert("Primer onclick"); }
boton.onclick = function() { alert("Segundo onclick"); }
```

```html
<button id="boton">PULSA</button>
```

Mi recomendación: si estás 100% seguro/a de que sólo vas a definir más de un `onclick` podrías usar este método con confianza.

---

### Detector de eventos: `object.addEventListener( "click", myScript);`

La principal ventaja de este métodos sobre los otros dos: te permite asociar más de un evento `click` al elemento y se ejecutarán en el mismo orden en el que fueron asociados. Además, y como en el método anterior, te permite el uso de clausuras, funciones anónimas, referencias a funciones, etc.

Por ejemplo, al siguiente botón le asignamos dos controladores del `click` y se ejecutan ambos:

```js
var boton = document.getElementById("boton");

boton.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("Primer click"); });
boton.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("Segundo click"); });
```

```html
<button id="boton">PULSA</button>
```

Un problema, como bien comentas, es que este método no funciona en versiones de IE anteriores a la 9 (en las que se podría usar el equivalente [`attachEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx)); pero teniendo en cuenta que [el soporte para todas las versiones de IE anteriores a la 11 terminó en Enero de 2016](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support), a no ser que tengas que soportarlas por algún motivo corporativo, deberías ignorar este problema.

Este sería el método que, a no ser que tengas restricciones de soporte, te recomendaría que usases.

---

### Usar bibliotecas: `$(elemento).on("click", function() { myScript }`

Sé que esto no estaba incluido dentro de los tres métodos que pusiste, pero creo que podría ser interesante añadirlo como alternativa. Las bibliotecas JavaScript te permitirán asociar eventos a los elementos y se saltarán algunos de los problemas que se describen arriba.

Por ejemplo: con jQuery se pueden asociar múltiples controladores al evento `click` (como con `addEventListener`), pero sin los problemas de compatibilidad que `addEventListener` presenta ya que el mismo código funcionará en *todas* las versiones de IE.

Con el ejemplo del botón anterior:

```js
$("#boton").on("click", function() { alert("Primer click"); });
$("#boton").on("click", function() { alert("Segundo click"); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="boton">PULSA</button>
```

Eso no quiere decir que todos debamos usar jQuery siempre: tiene sus cosas buenas y sus cosas malas (se estaría añadiendo una nueva fuente pesada, aunque tampoco mucho) y añadirlo a un proyecto sólo porque abstraiga mejor la asociación de eventos es una exageración y no merece la pena.

Comment: Excelente respuesta Alvaro, siempre aprendo cosas nuevas con tus aportes.

Comment: +1 Aunque yo matizaría lo de  "mi recomendación sería que no usases este método" (inline), anoto otra ventaja (obvia) de  los otros métodos: sirven también para elementos creados dinámicamente.

Comment: @leonbloy ¿qué pondrías para matizarlo?

Comment: El método inline se podría poner en elementos creados dinámicamente con `innerHTML`, por ejemplo: `midiv.innerHTML = "<button onclick='alert(123)'>PULSA</button>";` (sé que no es bonito, pero funciona)