# Necesito juntar 2 onclick en uno solo botón

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito juntos estos dos onclick en uno solo. He mirado varias páginas y no he sido capaz de hacerlo, gracias por su respuesta.

```html
<input value="pause" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()" type="button">
<input value="Mirar abajo" onclick="return mostrarOcultar('ocultable')" type="button">
```

Comment: Pausar y reproducir al mismo tiempo o como una especie de suiche?

Comment: perdon por no especificar bien, solo necesito 2 perdon,

Comment: <input value="pause" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').pause()" type="button">  <input value="Mirar abajo" onclick="return mostrarOcultar('ocultable')" type="button"

Comment: Dale, editala y contanos. Necesitas cuáles dos botones? Uno para pausar y reproducir y otro para mirar abajo?

Comment: lo unico que necesito es que cuando presione pause y me abra otro div que es aparte por eso necesito juantar las dos funciones

Comment: Mira esta pregunta, puede serte de ayuda: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25696/250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según tus comentarios. Haz un método:

```
function pausaMirarAbajo(){
  document.getElementById('demo').pause();
  mostrarOcultar('ocultable');
}
```

Y en el HTML colocas en un solo botón:

```
<input value="pausaMirarAbajo" onclick="pausaMirarAbajo()" type="button">
```

Así, ejecutas una función que se encarga de ejecutar las dos funciones que tenías en los botones con una sola ejecución.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo me funciono de maravilla me sacaste de un apuro :D